# Object doesn't support property or method 'confirm'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a `WebForm` which inherits from a `MasterPage` and in the `WebForm` I made use of jQuery and JavaScript which I am new to since I want to create a `dialog box` with customised buttons, and the default `confirm()` method does not allow any changes, so I have made use of resources and codes from [this website](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/). I'm not sure where to put the JS sources, so I have placed them in between (do tell me if I'm doing it wrong):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CSS" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

The sources I have from the reference are:

```
<script src="~/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script src="~/jquery.confirm.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

And as copied from the reference as well, this is my jQuery `dialog box`:

```
$("#Button1").confirm({
    title: "Confirmation Message",
    text: "Are you sure that the information you have entered is accurate?",
    confirm: function (button) {
        return true;
    },
    cancel: function (button) {
        return false;
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: "No"
});
```

This error always pops out whenever I try to run my code:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'confirm'.

I have tried using various JS sources and jQueries since I'm new to these but all of them didn't work. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: why have you included confirm.min,js and confirm.js both files?? only one is needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Button1').on('click', function () {
$.confirm({
    title: "Confirmation Message",
    text: "Are you sure that the information you have entered is accurate?"
    confirm: function (button) {
        return true;
    },
    cancel: function (button) {
        return false;
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: "No"
});
});
```

Comment: First try by removing any of the js file either  confirm.min,js or confirm.js...if it does not work try above solution..i hope any of one will work.

Comment: I tried your first suggested method, but both files didn't work individually either and pops out the same error message as mentioned. Then, I tried your solution. There wasn't any error but there was no dialog box either, it just went straight to submit.